# Iterate list to create single bucket policy with multiple principals

Tags: amazon-s3, terraform

I am creating a bucket and then a bucket policy to allow all the listed accounts access.  Seems to pass on terraform plan/apply, but looking at the console, only one account is listed, seems to be trampling previous policy adds.

I have a variable list and code to generate bucket/policy:

```
variable "accounts" {
    type = "list"
    default = [
         "111111111111",
         "222222222222",
         "333333333333",
         "444444444444",
         "555555555555",
         "666666666666",
         "777777777777"
    ]
}


resource "aws_s3_bucket" "my_bucket" {
  bucket = "${var.bucket_name}"
}
resource "aws_s3_bucket_policy" "my_bucket_policy" {
  bucket = "${aws_s3_bucket.my_bucket.id}"
  count = "${length(var.accounts)}"
  policy =<<EOF
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::${element(var.accounts, count.index)}:root"
            },
            "Action": "s3:PutObject",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::${var.bucket_name}/CloudTrail/AWSLogs/${element(var.accounts, count.index)}/*"
        }
    ]
}
EOF
}
```

Is there a way to just iterate the variable list in the Resource or Principal sections only?  Goal would be to generate a single bucket policy that has all arns from the variables.

Comment: Currently there is no for loop for this case to create rules for each account.

Answer (score 0):

Each bucket only supports one bucket policy, so you can't create multiple bucket policies.

Instead you can create multiple statements inside a single policy, one for each account. Terraform doesn't support iteration, but you can get much of the same effect using `formatlist()` and `join(`) functions.

```
resource "aws_s3_bucket_policy" "my_bucket_policy" {
  bucket = "${aws_s3_bucket.my_bucket.id}"
  policy =<<EOF
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        ${join(",\n",formatlist("
        {
            \"Effect\": \"Allow\",
            \"Principal\": {
                \"AWS\": \"arn:aws:iam::%s:root\"
            },
            \"Action\": \"s3:PutObject\",
            \"Resource\": \"arn:aws:s3:::%s/CloudTrail/AWSLogs/%s/*\"
         }
         ", var.accounts, var.bucket_name, var.accounts))}
    ]
}
EOF
}
```

In this case, I put the entire statement content as the first argument of a `formatlist()` function. It was necessary to escape the double quotes, but Terraform doesn't require newlines to be escaped. It contains `%s` where you want to put the replacements. The other `formatlist()` arguments are the replacements.

The output of `formatlist()` is a list, so I had to join the list into a single output string using the `join()` function. The `join()` function also allowed me to add the comma separators between each statement.